# How to display map using geocode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

My Script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var lat = <%= @town.latitude %>, 
 lon = <%= @town.longitude %>,
 map;
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
};
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    myOptions);
}
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps?file=api&  v=2.x&key="My api key"&libraries=places"></script>
```

I can fetch latitude and longitude but my map is not loading.Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working sample you can update it to your needs (remove what you dont need and add rails variables in place of static lat long):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: <%= @lat %>, lng: <%= @long %>},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourkey&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my sample Home controller index action code:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @lat = "43.8563"
    @long = "18.4131"
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank  you @Nezir. But my map is not displaying

Comment: Not displaying any error in console.I have changed the following                        **center: {lat: @town.latitude, lng: @town.longitude}**

Comment: can you create simple index.html file and paste this code above and just add your api key and try to open that index.html file in browser?

Comment: Yes,I have done that.It's working!!!.But my problem is i want to dynamically load lat and lang.How can we do that?

Comment: Updated code to use rails variables lat and long check this sample now

Comment: This is my controller where action is taking place:                                                                                                                      def town_view_map
    @town = Town.find params[:id]
   end                                                                                                                                 I added lat,lang which you specified,but there is no response

Comment: No sorry you need to practice with more  basic tutorials. If you dont know how to use this 2-3 working  lines I provided you above, you need to practice more with basic stuff.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! All the above worked,just got issue with my modal